# Horizon from VM is not working on Other devices

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, openstack, openstack-horizon

I'm totally new to openstack and vagrant virtualization.
after succeeding to setup openstack on some vagrant VM I noticed that horizon only workes on host and other machines recieve no respond.
Is there any way for other machines to receive horizon data too?

UPDATE:
my vagrant file:

```
# vi: set ft=ruby :


VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"


Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

config.vm.box = "controller"
#config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

config.vm.synced_folder "/home/parisa/vagrant/sync", "/home/vagrant/sync"

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.100"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.101"

config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
vb.name = "lighttpd-trusty"
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ostype", "Ubuntu_64"]
end


end
```

Comment: Can you share your Vagrantfile and your DevStack local.conf or localrc files? The issue is likely in how you set up networking for the VM.

Comment: I'm not using devstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out I should use :

```
config.vm.network "private_network"
```

instead of private network